# How to determine numerical stability condition?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

One has a ODE system of the form

$\frac{d}{dt}\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}a&b&c\\d&e&f\\g&h&i\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{bmatrix}$

Then, for example, to solve this by forward difference Euler method,
how to derive numerical stability condition,
which relates parameters $a$ to $i$ with sample rate i.e. time step $k$ ?

Comment: Have you considered the special case where the matrix can be diagonalized?

Comment: @CarlChristian  Yes, but I want to solve this without diagonalization, so I want to know general condition of numerical stability.

Comment: I know about numerical stability condition of ODE (one variable) but I can't find information about numerical stability condition of ODEs (variable is vector).

Comment: Can you solve the problem when your matrix is in Jordan normal form?